# Spring Data MongoDB converter from DBObject generates warning

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

After upgrading Spring Boot to 3.x, we see the following warning:

```
Registering converter from interface com.mongodb.DBObject to class <our class> as reading converter although it doesn't convert from a store-supported type; You might want to check your annotation setup at the converter implementation
```

Our Converter class signature looks like this:

```
@ReadingConverter
public static class MongoRead implements Converter<DBObject, xxx>
```

where xxx is our class.
I'm having trouble determining what we should do to follow best practices and eliminate the warning.